# How to make text start right below another text when they are both in the same li element

Tags: html, css

I am working on this vertical menu bar ground up. I am using responsive css shown at:[Responsive Web Design by W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp)
The thing is this list that I am making has 5 list items using Font awesome icons.
I have a media query setup for min-width of 768 px when i drop below that the text in menu items start going on the lines below.

[image: screenshot].

Is there any way i can align text so that they start right after the first line as in case u guys can see - services start from below the icon instead of network. I know that icons are text and hence I also tried text align but it didn't work. Please help guys.

If there is a way of aligning fonts in between both these lines it would also be helpful.

Comment: bro just add white-space:nowrap;

Comment: Yaah worked thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

On adding bootstrap, You should be able to place both the icon and the text right by each other using grids.

```
<div col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12>
<li>
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pie-chart"></span>
<b>Pie chart</b>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: But bro m not using bootstrap!!